# Why java String.split is ignoring last character is split is based on last character

Tags: java-8, java

If I run the following code:

```
"testx".split("x")
```

the expectation is that we will get `{"test", ""}`, but instead java is returning `{"test"}`

But `"xtest".split("x")` returns `{"", "test"}`. Any ides why its behaving weirdly (or) do I have the wrong understanding?

Here is my JDK & system info:

> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b6 amd64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> Linux 4.4.0-34-generic

Answer (score 8):

From [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) documentation:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. ***Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.***

If you want to preserve the trailing empty string then you can use [String.split(String, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) like this:

```
String str = "testx";
String[] values = str.split("x", -1);
```

Output:

```
{"test", ""}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get to force Java not to ignore end empty results?

Comment: @Kalinga Read that piece of quoted documentation again, and then think _"what would happen if I call the two-argument split method with a value other than zero for the limit argument"_ (or consult the documentation of [that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)) .

Comment: It would be easier to just use `str.split("x", -1)`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right. Edited.

Comment: Why does a String containing empty space character as last character gets returned 
when delimitter is an empty space character " " ?
  
Eg: `String s = "a ";
public static int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
    int l = 0;
    for(String eachWord : s.split("\\s+", -1)){
        if(!eachWord.equals(" ")){
            l = eachWord.length();
            System.out.println("'" + eachWord + "'");                
        }
    } 
    return l;
}`

returns 'a' and ' '.

Whereas, if `String s = "a a";`
then output is just 'a' followed by another 'a'

Why is this happening in Java 8?